# If $A$ skew hermitian matrix of order $n$ and $n$ be an even then prove that $\det A$ is a real number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> 1. If $A$ skew hermitian matrix of order $n$ and $n$ be an even then prove that $\det A$  is a real number.
> 2. If $A$ skew hermitian matrix of order $n$ and $n$ be an odd then prove that $\det A$  is purely imaginary number or zero.

$A$ skew hermitian matrix implies $A=-A^*$. But how to check the relationship with order $n$ and $\det A$ value. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\det A=\det((-1)A^*)=(-1)^n\cdot\overline{\det A}=\overline{\det A}$$

and now you do (2).

Comment: $\det(A^*)=\overline{\det A}$ Please explore this

Comment: @user1942348 What do you mean "explore this"? Didn't you mean "I must explore this..."? Yet it is trivial: $$A^*=\overline{A^t}\;,\;\;\text{and we know}\;\;\det A^t=\det A ...$$

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am unable to clear the following As $A^*=\overline{A^t}$ then $\det(A^*)=\det(\overline{A^t})=\det(\overline{A})=???$ Is $\det(\overline{A})=\overline{\det A}$? If yes please tell me how to get this.

Comment: The determinant function is a sum of products of entries of $\;A\;$. Since complex conjugation distributes both over addition and product, the result follows